# MATLAB: "Normalize" matrix elements to 1 or 0

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a rather large matrix (a few thousand elements) ranging from 0 to 255.
What is the easiest/most efficient way to set these elements to either 1 or 0 depending on if they are smaller or larger than a certain threshold value, for example 155?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply this:

```
A = A > threshold;
```

Comment: Wow! How beautiful! I'm new to MATLAB so this was really helpful.

Comment: The type of A after this assignment will be logical, not double. If it matters, you can explicitly cast back to double with "A=double(A>threshold);"